# como puedo usar un char para darle el nombre a un archivo en c?

Tags: c, archivo, begin-cbegin

mi duda es la siguiente, estoy aprendiendo a programar, estoy haciendo un programa en el que necesito guardar datos en distintos archivos por dia, y quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de crear un archivo y nombrarlo con los caracteres de un char ya existente. ejemplo tengo un char que tiene una fecha 15/10/21 y quiero que el archivo se llame 15/10/21.txt.

```
FILE *fopen(),*fp;


fp=fopen("datos.txt","w");
fclose(fp);
printf("datos.txt creado\n");
```

Comment: No me queda claro a qué te refieres por `char`. `char` es un tipo de dato para almacenar caracteres. Normalmente los archivos tienen más de uno, por lo que necesitarás un arreglo. O si se trata de un literal, con `char *` puedes tener una referencia a él.

Comment: Mi duda es la siguiente: tengo que crear un archivo y nombrarlo con una cadena de caracteres (char:nombre_archivo[20]), donde anteriormente guardo en esa cadena como lo voy a llamar. Por ejemplo: Enero_2019.txt.